# How can I append a div inside a image container in vue dynamically?

Tags: vue.js

I'm new to Vue, and I'm stuck here. I understand we can use `$el` to append div's to DOM dynamically as a child node. But how will I go about appending a div inside a image container dynamically. I'm using bootstrap vue.

```
<b-img 
   style= "position:relative"                      
   :id="'og'+(i+1)"
   :src="pageImage.pageValue"
   class="page-image"
 >
<div style="position:absolute; left:0; top: 0; height:100%; width:17%; border: 2px solid red;"/>
</b-img>
```

Comment: Did you already try something that failed? It'd be nice to have some code

Comment: Yes I did. I have added the code segment in question. Thanks for your reply :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While using Vue direct DOM manipulations are not preferred (Add/Remove child elements) as changes performed like this will no longer be reactive.

Rather you can find a solution of rendering a div element conditionally using vue v-if directive.

You can add some code over here and let us know what exactly you want to achieve so that we can give you an appropriate solution.

Below should work

```
<b-img 
   style= "position:relative"                      
   :id="'og'+(i+1)"
   :src="pageImage.pageValue"
   class="page-image"
 >
</b-img>

<div style="position:absolute; left:0; top: 0; height:100%; width:17%; border: 2px solid red;"/>
```

For adding borders dynamically all over image you can check the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/RiddhiParekh/zav3q8yk/21/) here.

```
<div id="app">
 <div style="position:relative;">
     <b-img src="https://picsum.photos/300/150/?image=41" fluid-grow alt="Fluid-grow image" ref="bimg" @load="details"></b-img>
     <div v-for="divborders in imgborders" :style="{left: `${(divborders-1)*20}px`, position:'absolute', top:' 0', height:'100%', width:'20px', border: '2px solid red'}"/>
</div>
</div>

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    imgborders: 0,
  },
  mounted() {
    this.$nextTick( () => {
    this.details();
    });
  },
  methods: {
    details() {
      this.imgborders = Math.floor(this.$refs.bimg.getBoundingClientRect().width/20);
    }
  }
})
```

Comment: I have added the code segment. basically I was testing this but it doesn't seem to work. What I want to achieve is to be able to draw boxes over the image dynamically over specific co-ordinates. so I thought I'll append div's for as many boxes. Any help is deeply appreciated

Comment: @YashGaur You just need to move your div element outside the <b-img> closing tag.

Comment: Okay, and If I want to do this dynamically?

Comment: By dynamic how do you want to add these borders?

Comment: By dynamically I mean I want to create as many div's as required over the image to basically draw the boxes over the image after the image is loaded. Or can I just use one div for that?? I feel dumb :D

Comment: Thanks @Riddhi, much appreciated.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/207599/discussion-between-yash-gaur-and-riddhi).